# Resetting Table content on button click wont work

Tags: javascript, html, reset, buttonclick

Hello everybody the toggle button hides certain elements of the table.
Whenever I try to toggle the table with another button after a previous toggle button is used the filter wont apply correctly, since the earlier toggled elements stay hidden.

I was reading that the resetfunction could reset the table, and i was trying to reset the table before every onclick togglefunction.

It would be great if someone could click another button without the need to click the same toggle button again for the elements to show up and the filters of another button to apply correctly.

No matter what I try the toggle buttons apply to the already toggled tables. The buttons should start toggling the list from its original state everytime though.
Any help would be highly appreciated.
Best Wished Tylah

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <button onclick="toggleDisplay ['Tim','3'];resetValues[''];">Toggle display</button>
    <button onclick="toggleDisplay ['Tim','Lea'];resetValues[''];">Toggle display</button>
    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">

    <table id="myTable">
      <tr>
        <th>Group</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="Tim">
        <td>soccer</td>
        <td>name</td>
        <td>Phone number</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="Lea">
        <td>basketball</td>
        <td>name</td>
        <td>9499494</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="3">
        <td>basketball/D</td>
        <td>Eau</td>
        <td>9499545494</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="3">
        <td>Hockey</td>
        <td>Eau</td>
        <td>9499545494</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="3">
        <td>Hockey</td>
        <td>Eau</td>
        <td>9499545494</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="3">
        <td>marathon</td>
        <td>Eau</td>
        <td>9499545494</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="3">
        <td>sprint</td>
        <td>Eau</td>
        <td>9499545494</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="3">
        <td>sprint</td>
        <td>Eau</td>
        <td>9499545494</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="3">
        <td>sprint</td>
        <td>Eau</td>
        <td>9499545494</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="3">
        <td>cross</td>
        <td>Eau</td>
        <td>9499545494</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="3">
        <td>cross</td>
        <td>Eau</td>
        <td>9499545494</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="3">
        <td>diskus</td>
        <td>Eau</td>
        <td>9499545494</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="3">
        <td>diskus</td>
        <td>Eau</td>
        <td>9499545494</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="3">
        <td>chess</td>
        <td>Eau</td>
        <td>9499545494</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="3">
        <td>chess</td>
        <td>Eau</td>
        <td>9499545494</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <script>
      function toggleDisplay(target) {

        let matches = document.querySelectorAll("." + target);
        matches.forEach(function (match) {

            if (match.style.display == "none")
              match.style.display = "block";

            else
              match.style.display = "none";
        });
    }

  function myFunction() {
    // Declare variables

    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query

    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
      td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];

      if (td) {
        txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;

        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
  }
  function resetValues() {
    document.getElementById("myTable").reset();

  </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out This code it is working fine

```js
function toggleDisplay(target) {
let matches = document.querySelectorAll("." + target);

matches.forEach(function (match) {
   if (match.style.display == "none")
       match.style.display = "block";

   else                
       match.style.display = "none";
});
}

function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables
var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
input = document.getElementById("myInput");

filter = input.value.toUpperCase();

table = document.getElementById("myTable");

tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

// Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
if (td) {
   txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
   tr[i].style.display = "";
} else {
tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }

    }

  }

}
function resetValues() {
  var table= document.getElementById("myTable");

var tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
   tr[i].style.display = "";
}
 
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleDisplay ['Tim'];resetValues();">Toggle display</button>
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
<th>Group</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Phone</th>
</tr>
<tr class="Tim">
<td>soccer</td>
<td>name</td>
<td>Phone number</td>
</tr>
<tr class="Lea">
<td>basketball</td>
<td>name</td>
<td>9499494</td>
</tr>
<tr class="3">
<td>basketball/D</td>
<td>Eau</td>
<td>9499545494</td>
</tr>
<tr class="3">
<td>Hockey</td>
<td>Eau</td>
<td>9499545494</td>
</tr>
<tr class="3">
<td>Hockey</td>
<td>Eau</td>
<td>9499545494</td>
</tr>
<tr class="3">
<td>marathon</td>
<td>Eau</td>
<td>9499545494</td>
</tr>
<tr class="3">

<td>sprint</td>
<td>Eau</td>
<td>9499545494</td>
</tr>
<tr class="3">

<td>sprint</td>

<td>Eau</td>

<td>9499545494</td>

</tr>
<tr class="3">

<td>sprint</td>

<td>Eau</td>

<td>9499545494</td>

</tr>
<tr class="3">

<td>cross</td>

<td>Eau</td>

<td>9499545494</td>
</tr>
<tr class="3">

<td>cross</td>

<td>Eau</td>

<td>9499545494</td>
</tr>
<tr class="3">
<td>diskus</td>
<td>Eau</td>
<td>9499545494</td>
</tr>
<tr class="3">
<td>diskus</td>
<td>Eau</td>
<td>9499545494</td>
</tr>
<tr class="3">
<td>chess</td>
<td>Eau</td>
<td>9499545494</td>
</tr>
<tr class="3">
<td>chess</td>
<td>Eau</td>
<td>9499545494</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
My aim is to have several buttons that toggle certain elements. 
And when i click a new button the table has to reset before so the filter applies correctly.
I have a botton soccer and basketball. 
When i click soccer all other elements should be hidden with the toggle function, and when i click on basketball all elements except basketball should be hidden.
The toggle function works but the elements stay hidden when i click the second button, so the toggle results are wrong

Comment: Sorry if i was unclear.
I am trying to reset toggle if another button that toggles as well is clicked